# Accessing bound functions from array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, bind

I have an array of objects containing references (bound by the `.bind()` method) to my class functions. When I access them directly, like `array[3].myFunction`, everything works fine. But the strange behavior occurs when I try to access these function iterating over the array. I've tried by `Array.forEach()`, for-in, for-of and `Array.map()` function, but the result is always the same - I get the first function four times. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

```js
var Container = function() {
  this.function1 = function() {
    console.log('function 1 invoked');
  };
  this.function2 = function() {
    console.log('function 2 invoked');
  };
  this.function3 = function() {
    console.log('function 3 invoked');
  };
  this.function4 = function() {
    console.log('function 4 invoked');
  };
  
  this.array = [
    { key: '1', myFunction: this.function1.bind(this) },
    { key: '2', myFunction: this.function2.bind(this) },
    { key: '3', myFunction: this.function3.bind(this) },
    { key: '4', myFunction: this.function4.bind(this) },
  ];
};

var container = new Container();

// Just printing the results below
console.log('direct access:');
console.log(container.array[3].myFunction);

console.log('forEach:');
container.array.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el.myFunction);
});

console.log('for in:');
for (let i in container.array) {
  console.log(container.array[i].myFunction);
}

console.log('map:')
container.array.map(el => {
  console.log(el.myFunction);
});
```

PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/mn8iGh4F3GcJXTNWXMiJ?p=preview

Comment: Since you're not actually calling these functions, all I get is `function () { [native code] }` (a bound function object) every time. With no way to distinguish it from the others.

Comment: If you actually call the function in those loops, not just log the function itself, the expected output occurs. My guess is a bug in `toString()`, at least in my Chrome version. You might want to point out that in Chrome, at least, it shows the function body for `function1` every time.

Comment: @Bergi see the result i.e. in the Chrome console

Comment: Chrome has some lazy evaluation stuff going on in its dev tools. Similar bug for arrays mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Comment: @Jacob, yes it works when I call them directly. But in my project there are passed further... Edit: Thanks, that's a trail!

Comment: I really think Chrome is just making you think the functions are the wrong values; it just has a buggy console. Try running in Firefox.

Comment: @DanielKucal This only happens in Chrome, try a different browser. Seems to be a bug with the devtools inspector indeed. You might want to report it to Google.

Comment: @Jacob that question shouldn't be relevant, since it deals with multiple logs of the same (but mutated) object. We do have distinct function instances in this example.

Comment: Interestingly, at least in my version of Chrome, it logs the correct function if you log the element first, like `console.log(el,el.myFunction);` or in the `for .. in` case, if you log `i` first.

Comment: Thank you both @Bergi and Jacob. I reported the bug to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look below. All seems to be working.

When you do `console.log(el.myFunction)`, it will actually print the `handle` and not executing it where all handle looks same as `function () { [native code] }`

When you invoke the function instead `el.myFunction()`, you can see all they are calling the right functions and print the results respectively.

You can check the function invocation below.

```js
var Container = function() {
  this.function1 = function() {
    console.log('function 1 invoked');
  };
  this.function2 = function() {
    console.log('function 2 invoked');
  };
  this.function3 = function() {
    console.log('function 3 invoked');
  };
  this.function4 = function() {
    console.log('function 4 invoked');
  };
  
  this.array = [
    { key: '1', myFunction: this.function1.bind(this) },
    { key: '2', myFunction: this.function2.bind(this) },
    { key: '3', myFunction: this.function3.bind(this) },
    { key: '4', myFunction: this.function4.bind(this) },
  ];
};

var container = new Container();

// Just printing the results below
console.log('direct access:');
container.array[3].myFunction();

console.log('forEach:');
container.array.forEach(el => {
  el.myFunction();
});

console.log('for in:');
for (let i in container.array) {
  container.array[i].myFunction();
}

console.log('map:')
container.array.map(el => {
  el.myFunction();
});
```